# difference in use cases between a normal pool and a keyed pool

Tags: java, pool

I'm looking at using pools for connection management and found http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/. Within the specifications, there are numerous strategies and I'm wondering how a keyed pool is different to a normal pool and how they might each be used.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in Clojure?

Comment: I am using clojure... And looking at examples of how the pooling library is used in carmine and casyn. But answers can be for java or clojure.

Comment: looks like a java question, what's clojure in it?

Comment: A java question could also be answered in clojure